# Fractional combination pick

Tags: probability

A factorial function for a fractional argument is defined in terms of the Gamma function.

If so, can $_n C_r$ be also defined for fractional $n,r$ ? ( For time being leaving aside what sense it might make).

Comment: See [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly we could say $_nC_r=\frac {\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(n-r+1)}$, which would agree with the usual definition when $n,r$ are naturals.  As you say, whether it is useful is to be determined.